# Hiding and disabling user interaction on a MapKit pin?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm trying to hide a pin on a MapKit view, and while setting the `hidden` property to `YES` works, I can still tap on it and get `didSelectAnnotationView` messages!. Naturally, I tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, but I'm still receiving the messages.

This is what I've tried. `a` is my annotation view.

```
a.hidden = YES; 
a.layer.hidden = YES;
a.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

There's something that I'm missing here, and I've Googled everywhere and can't find anything that works. Any clues?

Comment: You could check the visibilty of the pin in the didSelectAnnotationView, and just filter the ones which are visible. Just a quick workaround.

Comment: Thanks Mariusz, I thought about doing that but it I thought there must be a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `enabled` property of `MKAnnotationView` can be set to `NO` to disable selection as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW6) states:

> If the value of this property is NO, the annotation view ignores touch events and cannot be selected.