# Disable MKPlacemark showing/hiding title in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkplacemark

I have MKMapView with MKPlacemark on it. When showing the map, I'm showing place mark's title.
Everything is fine until now.

I want to disable hiding title when user touches it.

I tried to add

```
myMapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
myMapView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Which helps, but completely disables interaction with map. I want to leave a possibility to zoom in/out and moving the map.

Comment: not try on myMapView try With Title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *g in [myMapView gestureRecognizers]) 
        [myMapView removeGestureRecognizer:g];
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492308/hiding-and-disabling-user-interaction-on-a-mapkit-pin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating PIN, create your custom annotation. In custom annotation create the view with all the info that you want to present to user, and disable the place mark. By that you are not suppose to handle taps but you will show all the static/dynamic info attached to one lattitude/longitude.

Comment: I do have custom annotation. How do i disable the place mark?

Answer (score 0):

In MapKit Delegate method try bellow code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView  = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[yourMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
    if (annotation == yourMapview.userLocation)
        return nil;

    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    pinView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    //pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

    return pinView;
}
```

here if you use your placemark with this logic may its work....
hope,this help you...
:)