# Disable touches on MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, mkmapview, mapkit

When clicking MKAnnotationViews on a map they are temporarily brought to the front. I don't want this behaviour has I have a lot of MKAnnotationViews that are just icons on the map that don't have any other function.

I've tried setting the MKAnnotationView's `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` but it does not work. The MKAnnotationView still comes to the front when touched. This is confusing as MKAnnotationView is just a UIView so I can't work out why `userInteractionEnabled` is being ignored.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492308/hiding-and-disabling-user-interaction-on-a-mapkit-pin

Comment: @AnnaKarenina could you post that comment as answer so I close the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492308/hiding-and-disabling-user-interaction-on-a-mapkit-pin?lq=1) (and the documentation), to disable touches on an annotation view, you can set its `enabled` property to `NO`.

Setting `canShowCallout` to `NO` is a *potential* alternative.  However, that will not prevent the  `didSelectAnnotationView` and `didDeselectAnnotationView` delegate methods from still getting called (even though the callout will not be displayed).  That may be an issue depending on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
 (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 

//NSLog(@"my loc : %@",mapView.userLocation);

if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"any";

    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

    if ( pinView == nil )
      {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] ;
      }
//this property may help you  

    pinView.canShowCallout = NO;
}
```

Comment: oh thanx. is it really helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4 example**

We could reach our goal - **Disable touches** on MKAnnotationView **with** one really simple **delegate method**:

```
extension MyViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views {
        view.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

}

If the value of this property is false, the annotation view ignores touch events and cannot be selected. 
Combining with extension- and in summary, we get the elegant way of extending our ViewController with MKMapViewDelegate protocol conformance and unselectable MKAnnotationView!

Answer (score 0):

Set MKPinAnnotationView *pinView or MKAnnotationView *annotationView property of user interaction to NO  in the method where u have created them i.e

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
 (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

static NSString *annotation = @"identifier";

   MKAnnotationView * aView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

    if ( aView == nil )
      {
        aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotation] ;
      }
[aView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

Comment: Mentioned in my orignal question that I had tried that method.